# llamada a funcion y bucle for

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for

estoy tratando de comprender las funciones haciendo un ejercicio muy sencillo, pero que no consigo resolver el problema: Hago una pregunta de cuantas veces repetir `print ("hola")` y solo me repite una vez.

```
def repite_hola (repo):
    print ("numero de repeticiones: ", repo) 
    for x in repo:
        print ("hola")

repite=input("Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola? ")
repite_hola (repite)
```

> Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola? 3
>
> numero de repeticiones: 3
>
> hola

Alguna sugerencia? Saludos

Comment: `for x in range(repo):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repo` es una variable escalar, seguramente un cadena, por lo cual hacer `for x in repo:` producirá una sola iteración. El `for x in ..`  se usa pero con variables vectoriales, por ejemplo listas o bien con funciones generadoras como [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) que te permiten generar una secuencia de valores.

En primer lugar, asegurémonos que el input sea un entero:

```
repite = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola? "))
```

Teniendo ahora sí, un número, podremos producir el ciclo:

```
for x in range(repo):
   print ("hola")
```

Y ahora sí, con `range(repo)` generamos una secuencia inmutable de números de 0 a `repo` que pueden ser usados por el `for in ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Modificando un poco tu codigo:

```
 def repite_hola_en_linea (repo):
    print ("numero de repeticiones: ", repo) 
    valor ='hola'*repo
    print(valor)

def repite_hola_saltando (repo):
    print ("numero de repeticiones: ", repo) 
    for i in range(repo):
        print('hola')
repite = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola?: "))
print('hola en linea....')
repite_hola_en_linea (repite)
print()
print('hola saltando....')
repite_hola_saltando (repite)
```

Modifique esto: `repite = int(input("Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola?: "))` lo convertir a entero.
Despues `valor = 'hola' * repo` .Aca estamos multiplicando la palabra `hola` por la cantidad de veces que es introducida por teclado y al final imprimirla, como resutlado  obtenemos:

```
Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola?: 3
hola en linea....
numero de repeticiones:  3
holaholahola

hola saltando....
numero de repeticiones:  3
hola
hola
hola
```

Comment: no creo que el OP quiera que todo se vea en una sola línea

Answer (score -2):

Muy buena explicación Patricio.
Para que tengas una idea tal cual realizaste tu código, te comparto la solución.

```
def repite_hola (repo):
    print ("numero de repeticiones: ", repo) 
    for x in range(int(repo)):
        print ("hola")

repite=input("Cuantas veces quieres repetir hola? ")
repite_hola (repite)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] El código debe estar en texto, échale un vistazo a [answer]  Un saludo

Comment: La función debería recibir un entero, no un string. Es una función que hace algo un **número** de veces; debe recibir un **número**, no un string.